# Maximum likelihood estimate for geometric distribution from table

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, estimators, geometric-distribution

I am asked to compute the MLE of the parameter p of the geometric distribution and then apply it to some given data. It is easy to find the MLE:
[image: MLE for geometric distribution]

But how do I apply it to these data:

```
+-------------------------------+
| Count   1   2   3    4   5  ≥6 |
+-------------------------------+
| Freq   902 403 106  38  16  4  |
+-------------------------------+
```

Normally I would just compute the mean: multiply the count with the freq, add everything and divide by n, then take the reciprocal. But in this case, I cannot apply this method, because I do not know the counts for the last frequencies.

I asked and I was told that it is only necessary to know the probabilities and the frequency, not the counts. The question also has a hint: [image: hint]

The data corresponds to the number of occupants in private
cars on a certain road. I take [image] to be the ith count (number of occupants) and n = 1469 is the number of cars (samples).

Any help for this simple problem is appreciated!

Comment: The verbal description following "normally" does not appear to match the formula for the MLE.  Could you therefore explain what "$n$" and the "$x_i$" in the formula mean and how they correspond to your description?